# Set a range with a string/cell contents

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing some code for a client which pulls data from many differently laid out files. I wanted to write something which was quite flexible for him in the future.

Therefore, he will be able to write for example `y.offset(0,1)` in a cell depending where in regards to the variable `y` the data will be.

The reason I haven't just made the the variable `1` is because it, and therefore the cell, may or may not include multiple & "blah blah"

Basically, I'm wondering if it's possible to write parts of code in a cell then pull them up and incorporate them into code.

For instance:

```
Dim y as range
Dim x as range
Dim c as string

Set Y = Sheet1.range("G4")
c = sheet1.range("A1")     [which contains the words y.offset(0,4)
Set x = c
```

This doesn't work, however I'm wondering if there's anything that can be done to get the same result.

Comment: Can you give a more detailed description of why you need that? In your example it would be easier to just ask for a cell reference in `A1` or `R1C1` notation.

Comment: There is `application.evaluate` which could process something like `OFFSET(Sheet1!G4, 0, 4)` but I don't know of any way to process a string as a VBA operation.

Comment: You could always create an UDF with input from a cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your need is kind of a *recursive* and dangerous one

then it deserves such a *recursive* and dangerous answer

you could use the VBA Project Object Model (see [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx) for info) and act as follows:

1. Set your project to handle VBA Object Model

   follow all the steps you can see in the *Introduction* of the above given link to cpearson website Add reference to your project

   Disclaimer: please also read the **CAUTION** note in there
2. add "helper" module

   add to your project a new Module and call it after "HelperModule" (you can call it as you like, but then be consistent with the chosen name)

   then add this code into this new module

   ```
   Function GetRange(refRng As Range) As Range
      Set GetRange = refRng 
   End Function


   Function SetToCellContent(refRng As Range, cellContent As String) As Range
       UpdateCodeModule cellContent
       Set SetToCellContent = HelpModule.GetRange(refRng)
   End Function

   Sub UpdateCodeModule(cellContent As String)
       Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
       Dim LineNum As Long

       Set CodeMod = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("HelperModule").CodeModule
       LineNum = SearchCodeModuleLine(CodeMod, "Set GetRange")
       CodeMod.ReplaceLine LineNum, "    Set GetRange = " & cellContent
   End Sub

   Function SearchCodeModuleLine(CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule, FindWhat As String) As Long
       Dim SL As Long ' start line
       Dim SC As Long ' start column
       Dim EL As Long ' end line
       Dim EC As Long ' end column
       Dim Found As Boolean

       With CodeMod
           SL = 1
           EL = .CountOfLines
           SC = 1
           EC = 255
           Found = .Find(Target:=FindWhat, StartLine:=SL, StartColumn:=SC, EndLine:=EL, EndColumn:=EC, wholeword:=True, MatchCase:=False, patternsearch:=False)
       End With

       SearchCodeModuleLine = SL
   End Function
   ```
3. Add this code to your main code

   ```
   Set x = SetToCellContent(y, c) '<--| call the function that will take care of updating code in 'GetRange()' function and returns a range relative to 'y' as per the "code" in 'c'
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the answers. That link was amazing and I will definitely book mark it for future reference (keeping in mind the caution).

Comment: you are welcome. and if I fulfilled your question (I actually tested it before answering and it worked), then please mark it as accepted. Thank you